# Zip a Set with an ordered Int

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to `zip`a `Set` in Haskell without having to convert it to a `List` first?

I want a function that creates a set of Vertices from a given Edge data. A vertex is basically a pair of index and its data.

```
data Vertex a = Vertex { idx::Int, cont::a }

toVertexSet :: S.Set String -> S.Set (Vertex String)
toVertexSet = undefined

toStringSet:: [(String, String, Int)] -> S.Set String
toStringSet = foldl insertToSet S.empty where
    insertToSet set (vfrom, vto, _) =
        case (S.member vfrom set, S.member vto set) of
            (True, True) -> set
            (True, False) -> S.insert vto set
            (False, True) -> S.insert vfrom set 
            (False, False) -> S.insert vto (S.insert vfrom set)
```

Basically I want `toVertexSet` to pair each `String` with a unique `Int` as an index, ordered from 1 to the size of the set, turning it into a Set of vertices. Is there a better way to do this without having to convert the set back to a List first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sets are foldable so you could use a fold:

```
import Data.Foldable (foldl')

data Vertex a = Vertex { idx::Int, cont::a } deriving (Eq, Ord)

toVertexSet :: S.Set String -> S.Set (Vertex String)
toVertexSet = snd . foldl' (\(i, vs) s -> (i+1, S.insert Vertex { idx = i, cont  = s } vs)) (1, S.empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `zip` to achieve that, my current solution is to derive `Eq` on `Vertex` based on its contents so that it can be stored in a Set directly, and using helper function which carries last inserted index as additional parameter. I lost the elegant fold, though.

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Vertex a) where
    v1 == v2 = cont v1 == cont v2

instance (Eq a, Ord a) => Ord (Vertex a) where 
    v1 `compare` v2 = cont v1 `compare` cont v2

toVertexSet:: [(String, String, Int)] -> S.Set (Vertex String)
toVertexSet = insertToSet 0 S.empty where
    insertToSet _ set [] = set 
    insertToSet ix set ((vfrom, vto, _):rest) =
        let newVertex  = Vertex ix
            nvfrom     = newVertex vfrom
            nvto       = newVertex vto
            incrOne (Vertex i m) = Vertex (i + 1) m
        in case (S.member nvfrom set, S.member nvto set) of
            (True, True) -> insertToSet ix set rest
            (True, False) -> insertToSet (ix + 1) (S.insert nvto set) rest
            (False, True) -> insertToSet (ix + 1) (S.insert nvfrom set) rest
            (False, False) -> insertToSet (ix + 2) (S.insert (incrOne nvfrom) 
                                (S.insert nvto set)) rest
```